# Vector and element on the heap

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to understand the concept of heap and the stack, so I need to create a vector which its elements are stored in the heap. So far I have done the followings:

```
class Car {
public:
Car(){
    Car->resize(0);
    Size = 0;
}

 private:
std::vector<int>* CarVector = new std::vector<int>;
size_t Size;
};
```

Comment: A `std::vector` already allocates its storage dynamically ("on the heap"), and also provides its own size.

Comment: @Quentin, Thank you very much. I understood from your comment that when I try to d
std::vector<int> vector = [0,1,2] It allocates the storage  on the stack. 
But, in case of
std::vector<int> vector = new std::vector<int> it allocates the storage  on the heap.

Comment: Not quite. The `std::vector` object itself will be allocated in whichever way you requested, but its elements will *always* be dynamically allocated -- that's the whole purpose of this container.

Comment: You also should post code that compiles.

Comment: Think of `std::vector<T>` using `new T[]` when it needs to be resized and storing this as a private member variable `T*`. That's not exactly what happens, but for understanding what's dynamically allocated and what's not, this is sufficient. In `int main() { std::vector<int> v; v.resize(100); }`  the vector object is stored on the stack, but the backing storage used to store the elements is allocated on the heap.